# How can iterate over a list of objects, and assign watches to their variables, and use one of their callbacks?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch

Here's a jsfiddle that does exactly what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/4evvmqoe/1/
(with the exception of those initial alerts... is there a way to suppress those?).

HTML:

```
    <div ng-app="">
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
          <div ng-repeat = "x in items">
          <input type = "checkbox" ng-model = "x.bool"/>
           {{x.label}}
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
   function MyCtrl($scope) {
    var CheckBox = function(label, fn){
        this.label = label;
        this.fn = fn;
        this.bool = true;
    }
    $scope.items = [
        new CheckBox("aaaa", function(){alert("aaa")}),
        new CheckBox("bbbb",  function(){alert("bbb")}),
        new CheckBox("cccc",  function(){alert("ccc")})
    ];
    for (var i = 0;  i< $scope.items.length; i++){
        $scope.$watch('items['+i+']', function(newValue, oldValue){
            newValue.fn();
        }, true);
    }
}
```

What concerns me is my code to do the watches:

```
  for (var i = 0;  i< $scope.items.length; i++){        
    $scope.$watch('items['+i+']', //<-- seriously?
       function(newValue, oldValue){ 
        newValue.fn();      
    }, true);
  }
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Questions:

1. How do I suppress the initial alerts?
2. Is `$scope.$watch('items['+i+']',` really the right way to do this? I mean it works but... I feel like there's some kind of awful performance issue at stake.

Comment: You could simply use $scope.$watchCollection to look trough an array.. Look it up on google

Comment: @SmileApplications - That would watch the array as a whole, and wouldn't let me assign individual callbacks.

Comment: But you can check the differences between the old one and the new one and get the one that changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify watch to see if values changed and only call your function if it has been changed

```
$scope.$watch('items['+i+']', function(newValue, oldValue){
  if(newValue !== oldValue){
    newValue.fn();  
  }    
}, true);
```

Watches are expensive and you could get rid of `$watch` and use `ng-change` on checkboxes instead which would be more performant

eg.

http://jsfiddle.net/qbuLk2gd/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat = "x in items">      
      <input type = "checkbox" ng-model = "x.bool" ng-change = "x.fn()"/>
       {{x.label}}
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {    
    var CheckBox = function(label, fn){
    this.label = label;
    this.fn = fn;
    this.bool = true;
  }

  $scope.items = [
    new CheckBox("aaaa", function(){alert("aaa")}), 
    new CheckBox("bbbb",  function(){alert("bbb")}), 
    new CheckBox("cccc",  function(){alert("ccc")})
  ];      
}
```

Much simpler!

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4evvmqoe/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Ok, that solves that initial bit. The question is more about the code to watch each object, and assign the callback.

Comment: Well then you need to revise question ... that's not what you asked and not clear what you are asking now

Comment: As far as better way...yes....watches are expensive if you have a lot of items, can use `ng-change` on checkbox and get rid of `$watch`

Comment: Yup! That's probably the right answer! Edit that into your answer and I'll accept it tomorrow.